# Adding a fragment above another fragment's layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know It might be a vary basic question to ask. I am trying to add a fragment say Fragment A above Fragment B. Usually while adding a fragment, we add it to the Activity layout. But right now, I am trying to add Fragment A to Fragment B layout so that user can view Frag A above Frag B whenever he navigates only to Frag B but not to other Fragments. The issue is Fragment A doesn't cover the full layout and is covering only a part of Frag B. I will post my code below. Please help.

Inside Frag B.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/page_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
android:id="@+id/scan_layout"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupScan"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Registered"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_left_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/radio_registered"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Available"
        android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_right_selector"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/radio_available"/>
</RadioGroup>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/scantoolListRegistered">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/scantoolListAvailable">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="No Tools Available."
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/notool"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

And Inside FragB.java I am writing:

```
  blankFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.scan_layout, blankFragment).commit();
```

Comment: So FragA is in a activity right ? Why are you not using the same container where FragA is added ?. Add FragB also in the same container.

Comment: @sunilsunny: Frag B is added to the activity container. My goal is to show Frag A only when user moves to FragB but not in other fragments. I just need to show FragA above FragB when I move to Frag B. In case of activity, its not happening

Comment: @AnimeshJena you can use a frame layout that covers your complete layout then use        FragmentTransaction to override fragment a on fragment b or vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `activity.xml` you can place two (Frame)Layouts and treat them like a fragment container.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Do this to open another a fragment from another fragment:

```
openDialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening custom dialog");
        customDialogFragment customDialogFragment = new customDialogFragment();
        customDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this,/*requestCode*/ 1);
        customDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "/*tag*/ MycustomDialogFragment");
    }
});
```

Comment: Class names should be capitalised to avoid class name / variable name confusion like in here.